# What will I miss by jumping straight into ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I come from a computer science type background (lots of [usaco](http://www.usaco.org/) style problems), working mainly in **C/C++** and recently decided that I wanted to get into **web development**. I have some experience with **C#** making basic **Windows Forms Applications** as well.

I spent some time researching what seemed to be my two best options: *PHP/MySQL* or *ASP.NET* MVC. I figured that I would go with **ASP.NET** largely because I was much more familiar with strongly typed languages and although I am more of a linux/vim fan, I am comfortable using VS.

I have a fairly basic knowledge of html/CSS and was expecting to develop this further as I followed my ASP.NET MVC web dev path; however, after starting to go through some tutorials/information, I am noticing how abstracted everything seems to be with html helpers etc. Am I going to learn all the fundamentals of web development or am I just going to learn how to develop sites within this particular environment? If so, what might a checklist of prerequisite web development knowledge look like? that I can go through before proceeding with ASP.

Could a case be made for starting with PHP/MySQL to learn how everything fits together, without an IDE organizing and abstracting everything for me, and then proceeding with ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Why not just not use the helpers?

Comment: I think, java is a more common choice server-side. ASP.MVC force you to use windows as the hosting-environment (or you build on top of Mono). Windows as an hosting-environment is an highly controversial topic...

Comment: @Ron StackOverflow seems to do just fine with Windows..

Comment: @Ben Parsons: Maybe it's the science background coming out--wanting to know exactly how something is working; however I was thinking, maybe in the future I might need to edit some raw html (or something else abstracted in VS) and I won't know what to do as I am used to just using helpers.

Comment: Right, so my suggestion is to not use the helpers at first, then when  you know what they're doing for you, use them if needed. There is more to ASP.NET MVC than the HtmlHelper methods.

Comment: @stariz77 you can still use standard HTML in MVC. You're not restricted to using helpers, though it is recommended that you use those.

Comment: Maybe this is more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Stuart Facebook uses PHP. So, you want to recommend PHP because of that?

Comment: @Ron Facebook also uses .NET alongside PHP.

Comment: @Liam: Can you provide any further information on this? Link?

Comment: @Ron as far as I am aware the API is entirely .NET, though I'm not sure where I read it.

Comment: @Liam I dont know, if they had some .net-based code on their platform in the past, but it seems that there are no plans to grow that particular department... http://www.facebook.com/careers/department?dept=engineering

Comment: @Ron aye, my information is probably out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been an ASP.MVC based developer for a while now and I recently picked up a PHP/MySQL project in my spare time that utilizes CodeIgniter, which is a similar MVC framework for MVC. If anything, ASP.NET MVC has helped me out with my learning when picking up a new language, especially when that language also has the ability to utilize a similar MVC Framework.

My opinion would be to dive straight in to ASP.NET MVC. You have better tooling, better support and resources and I'd say it's easier to get your head around as it's not a scripting language like PHP.

In comparison to other .NET/non-.NET tech that I've used, MVC is far easier to understand and pick up. Though that's just based on my personal experience.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP is like smoking. It harms you, but you cant stop using it, because you feel comfortable with it. Better not starting it :).

I would recommend you to look at java-based frameworks like Grails or Play!. Java has a long tradition on the server side and many(!) resources on the web.

In addition to that, IDEs like Eclipse are like sugar. You should know these things before choosing the final environment!

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not miss anything by starting with PHP/MySQL. You should start with ASP.NET MVC3 right away.

Starting with PHP/MySQL will only give you more headaches.

But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net MVC  is vary much close to the Web architecture of Request and Response as oppsed to asp.net
so leae aside that it ill abstract away that from you
talking of helpers.. well actually Helpers are there just to help you "CAN" use them if you want to
 if you ask me i would say just use them from now make something you will gain confidence and then make your way up into the abstraction(as is they there arnt much just in the HTML Helpers).

also learning Asp.net MVC would later allow you to learn the Web Api with ease(same underlying principles) but it is right there in terms actually web architecture

apart from these asp.net mvc comes with better tools and c#(a strngly typed lang) to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's about what you want to achieve. If the goal is to develop good web applications, you might as well jump straight into a framework and start developing.

Coming from a CS type background myself, I decided to learn the "hard way". I started off with the book [Teach Yourself HTML and CSS in 24 Hours](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328410): I then went on by learning the server side through PHP. No framework or anything, just plain PHP and raw SQL for database connections.

As I have grown more experienced, and the tasks more complicated the need for a robust framework has become clear. Developing full scale web applications without some kind of MVC framework seems "impossible", and maintaing it would be a headache. Scaffolding and templating is powerful, and will save you a lot of time as a web developer.

All of the above is things that can't be achieved without a framework, so as I said initially: It all comes down to your goals.
Do you want to learn how the web works? Go the long, hard, manual way. Do you want to get that webapp up and running? Go with the framework.